# Is there a way to dynamically manipulate the spellcheck dictionary?

Tags: macos, dictionary, spellcheck, spelling

I would like to have a way to dynamically add and remove words from the system-wide dictionary in Mountain Lion. The use-case is:

1. I'm working on a piece of fiction that has a lot of odd names in it that I would like spell-checked -- hit some key-combination that loads those odd name into the dictionary list of known words
2. I'm done working on the fiction and I no longer want those words polluting my dictionary -- hit some key-combo to unload those words from the dictionary

I could be working on two separate pieces of fiction and would want to load and unload each list separately. I'm not looking for an app with a custom spell-checker; I'm definitely looking for something that works with the built-in, system-wide spell checking sub-system.

All solutions considered: open source, paid applications, AppleScript, Automator, shell scripts -- anything and everything.

Answer (score 1):

When you press the Learn button, the word is added to `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` if the language is set to automatic or to `~/Library/Spelling/en` if the language is set to U.S. English. `en_GB` is used for British English and `en` is used only for U.S. English.

If you edit the files in `~/Library/Spelling/` directly, you can apply the changes by terminating the `AppleSpell` process.

So try to [assign a shortcut to a script](http://osxnotes.net/shortcuts.html) like this:

```
cd ~/Library/Spelling
if [[ -e fiction ]]; then
  mv en normal; mv fiction en; d=fiction
else
  mv en fiction; mv normal en; d=normal
fi
killall AppleSpell
terminal-notifier -title "Using dictionary $d" -message '' -group spellingdictionary
sleep 3
terminal-notifier -remove spellingdictionary
```

If for example you use the British English dictionary, change `en` to `en_GB`.

You can install `terminal-notifier` with `sudo /usr/bin/gem install terminal-notifier`.